# How to slice a list into 2 parts based on percentage?

Tags: python, arrays, numpy, deep-learning, training-data

I need to split my array into two parts the first one needs to have the first 90% and the next one should have the rest. But I get a corrected result for only the second array.

ex: from 11500 I get 1150 for test_images but I get 11500 for tain_images.

```
tain_images, test_images = np.split(imagesArr, [int(len(imagesArr)*0.9)])
```

Comment: can you provide your code?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

you should use sklearn [`train_test_split()`](https://scikit-learn.org/stable/modules/generated/sklearn.model_selection.train_test_split.html#sklearn-model-selection-train-test-split)

```
from sklearn.model_selection import train_test_split

train_images, test_images  = train_test_split(imagesArr, test_size=0.1)
```

change the `test_size` value according to the required test dataset percentage.

Answer (score 0):

your code works for me. It could be that you have a typo somewhere, for example a typo in `tain_images` somewhere later in your code.

Answer (score 0):

It works for me :

```
import numpy as np
imagesArr = []
for i in range(11500):
    imagesArr.append(str(i+1))
imagesArr = np.array(imagesArr)
tain_images, test_images = np.split(imagesArr, [int(len(imagesArr)*0.9)])
print(len(tain_images))
print(len(test_images))
```

Result :

```
10350
1150
```